# Minimum separation of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I have three MOSFET in a row, each separated about 2.5mm apart with the backs facing each other. Is this a good idea?

N.B
Each MOSFET will be sinking 20mA and 60 mA in total for all three MOSFET. I am using an IRF540. The schematic below is for ONE MOSFET.

[image]

Comment: yes it's fine. worse-case, one switches the other on if they get bent.

Comment: Arduino's are often used to drive MOSFETs to sink current for higher loads, so this seems perfectly on topic to me.  I even made a board with 4 shift registers and 32 1A MOSFETs http://www.crossroadsfencing.com/BobuinoRev17/ for driving LED strips and small motors from an Arduino.

Comment: @CrossRoads Arduino was created in Ivrea, Italy. Does this mean that on arduino.stackexchange travelling questions to Italy are on topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power dissipation is only a couple of milli-watts. So heat is not an issue.

Just make sure the metal tabs can’t touch each other. Personally I might add some Kapton tape. Electrical tape would work in this case, but feel wrong to me.